# Generate english versions of same content on Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, internationalization, multilingual

My website needs to be able to support multiple languages for multiple countries. For example, the US might have English and Spanish, while the UK might only have English. If two countries use the same language, it DOES NOT mean the content is the same.

For this reason, I decided to use the internationalization module (i18n) and I created language codes as follows:

```
gb-en - UK English
us-en - US English
us-es - US Spanish
```

I set this up with no issues, but my problem comes in with creating all the default content. For each content type, I want to:

1. Set the content types default language as "English"
2. Create translated versions of each content type for each language

I know this will mean that the Spanish content would still be in English, but it's the first step towards translating it.

What is the easiest way to create all these "default" content pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a module implementing [hook_node_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7). This module would intercept the creation of a new node (stored with the default language) and create as many copies as needed. Each of these copies should have a different value in the field language. These copies colud be easily stored in the dabase using [node_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) function.

Comment: So there is no other way other than writing code manually to do it, hey?

Comment: I have not found an easier way.